# Hide specific cells in table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table, show-hide

I've created a table and I need to hide specific cells of the table. Following is the table:

[image: Table screenshot]

And this is the source code:

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span style="color:red">Note: Fields marked with red * are mandatory</span><br>            
    </td>
    <td>
        <span style="color:white;font-weight:bold;background-color:blue">Forecast Controls:</span><br>            
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span>Program Name</span><br>            
    </td> 
    <td>
        <span class="setStyle" data-displayName="Program Name"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span style="color:green">Forecast In Progress</span><br>            
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="setStyle" data-displayName="Forecast In Progress"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span>Project Definition<span style="color:red">*</span></span><br>            
    </td> 
    <td>
        <span class="setStyle" data-displayName="Project Definition"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span style="color:blue">No Changes in Forecast for this Month</span><br>            
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="setStyle" data-displayName="No Changes in FC"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span>FCP #<span style="color:red">*</span></span><br>            
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="setStyle" data-displayName="FCP #"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span style="color:green">Send to Review</span><br>            
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="setStyle" data-displayName="Send to Review"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span>Value Contract #<span style="color:red">*</span></span><br>            
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="setStyle" data-displayName="Value Contract #"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span style="color:green">Reviewed</span><br>            
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="setStyle" data-displayName="Reviewed"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span>FAS ID<span style="color:red">*</span></span><br>            
    </td> 
    <td>
        <span class="setStyle" data-displayName="FAS ID"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span style="color:blue">Mark Project as Inactive?</span><br>            
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="setStyle" data-displayName="Mark as Inactive"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I would like to toggle between hiding and showing the "Send to Review" text and checkbox which is highlighted in red using jquery .hide() and .show()

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything? Look for jQuery selecting elements this is a good example: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Comment: when do you want to hide and show?
Your html is not enough. There is no input and checkbox

Comment: For example when you press two buttos, one to hide it and the other to show it.